# upload image to folder

Tags: php, image, upload

I'm making a form where the user can upload a picture to a folder. I've got this code

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "portfolio");

$query = null;

$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$image_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if ($image_name != '' && ($image_type = "image/jpeg" || $image_type = "image/png" || $image_type = "image/gif"))
    if (move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name, "project_pics/$image_name"))

        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (name, photo) VALUES('$image_name','images/$image_name')");

if ($query == true) {
    echo 'Image uploaded';
    echo "<img src='project_pics/$image_name'";
}

else {
    echo 'Please select an image';
    exit();
}
```

Everytime I try to upload an image I get the echo from my else "Please select an image"

I have no idea what the problem is.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I'm also trying to store the image name and path in a database. Forgot to mention that

Comment: echo "<img src='project_pics/'".$image_name."' />";

Comment: Have you chedked if $_FILES['image'] is actually populated? Eg. `print_r($_FILES);` . Perhaps you are missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your <form> element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix `mysql` and `mysqli` (...you can, but not the way you are doing it).

`mysql_query(....` cannot be anything but `false` because there is no connection.

You started with `mysqli_connect()`.

To quote php.net:

> Returns `FALSE` on failure. For successful `SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN` queries `mysqli_query()` will return a `mysqli_result` object. For
>   other successful queries `mysqli_query()` will return `TRUE`.

The best is to check with either davidkonrad's method or `($query !== false)`

Comment: Thanks man. Forgot to make a mysql query. Works like a charm now!

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query function returns resource, and you  are checking true

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "portfolio");

$query = null;

$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$image_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if ($image_name != '' && ($image_type = "image/jpeg" || $image_type = "image/png" || $image_type = "image/gif")){
    if (move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name, "project_pics/$image_name"))
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (name, photo) VALUES('$image_name','images/$image_name')") or die(mysql_error());


    echo 'Image uploaded';
    echo "<img src='project_pics/$image_name'";
} else {
    echo 'Please select an image';
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to take care some things

1. make sure. your form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
2. change `mysql_query` to `mysqli_query`.

   ```
   $query = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO images (name, photo)  
   VALUES('$image_name','images/$image_name')");
   ```